# base href taking incorrectly and no idea from where its taking

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular6, ng-build

I am taking a base url in html as

```
<base href="https://namwebsite.com/demo/prjFolder/">
```

When I run `ng build --prod` and host the generated files in the server,
I get the following error.

The prob is it is not adding slash after prjFolder and hence the path is getting invalid.

Anybody has any idea about this and a solution to fix this issue.

I even tried but still same error

```
ng build --prod --base-href https://namwebsite.com/demo/prjFolder/
```

index.html file :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://namwebsite.com/demo/prjFolder/">


</head>
<body>

  <app-root></app-root>

</body>
</html>
```

Error :

> GET https://namwebsite.com/demo/prjFolderstyles.2cd1dd7108e063f57822.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
>       demo.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: APlayer is not defined
>           at demo.js:1
>       (anonymous) @ demo.js:1
>       3/:50 GET https://namwebsite.com/demo/prjFolderpolyfills.f6ae3e8b63939c618130.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
>       ppomap.js:9 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
>           at initialize (ppomap.js:9)
>           at ppomap.js:88
>       initialize @ ppomap.js:9
>       (anonymous) @ ppomap.js:88
>       /:41 GET https://namwebsite.com/demo/prjFolderstyles.2cd1dd7108e063f57822.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
>       3/:50 GET https://namwebsite.com/demo/prjFolderruntime.a4802852034188678b29.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Comment: can you show us index.html code.

Comment: This seems to be a bug. [Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7295).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your domain `https://namwebsite.com`,
and you have created **sub-directory**, like `/demo/prjFolder/`

So you can select any one option below -

(**Manually, in the generated `dist` folder,** **index.html** **file**)

So you just need to add the relative path eg. `<base href="/demo/prjFolder/">`

**(Using `build` command)**

eg. `ng build --prod --base-href /demo/prjFolder/`

[More Help](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

Comment: What is your base Url and Also name the directory which you have created, after public_html folder.